# FindRoot does not work with Piecewise including complex-valued function

Tags: numerics, complex

Suppose we have the following `Piecewise` function:

```
gg[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{x^4 - 6 x^3 + 5, x <= 1}, {8 x^2 - x^7, x > 1}}]
```

We can find the root of the function easily by:

```
FindRoot[gg[x], {x, 10}]
(* {x -> 1.51572} *)
```

The problem emerges when we make for example the second function complex:

```
gcom[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{x^4 - 6 x^3 + 5, x <= 1}, {8 x^2 - x^7 I, x > 1}}]
```

In this case `FindRoot` does not work:

```
FindRoot[gcom[x], {x, 10}]

LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 1.24121 -0.147854 I attempted.

Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1.24121 -0.147854 I attempted.

LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 1.24121 -0.147854 I attempted.

Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1.24121 -0.147854 I attempted.

FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {\[Piecewise]   -3.813+2.96586 I    1.24121 -0.147854 I<=1
8.6317 -6.15431 I   1.24121 -0.147854 I>1
0   True

} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.24121 -0.147854 I}.
```

Note that outside the `Piecewise` function Mathematica can find the complex root:

```
FindRoot[8 x^2 - x^7 I, {x, 10}]

(* {x -> 1.44153 - 0.468382 I} *)
```

So my question is how can I find the complex roots of a complex-valued function in a `Piecewise`?

Comment: The solution lies on a jump discontinuity of the function, right? How do you expect `FindRoot` to find that? Moreover, you equation is overdetermined: two real quations for one real parameter.

Comment: @Schumacher: I have a piecewise function with  two functions for x greater and smaller than 1.  It is my question: FindRoot can find the complex root of the function, but not inside a piecewise.

Comment: The problem is that your solution is complex, and your function `gcom` doesn't work with complex input, e.g., `gcom[1+I]` doesn't work. You need to change the conditions in your piecewise so that they work with complex input.

Comment: I don't think that `Piecewise` has meaning for a complex function. `FindRoot` must enter a complex number for your argument. How will `Piecewise` deal with this. Perhaps you need to define branch cuts.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `gcom[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{x^4 - 6 x^3 + 5, Re[x] <= 1}, {8 x^2 - x^7 I, Re[x] > 1}}];
FindRoot[gcom[x], {x, 10}]`?

Comment: @Schumacher: Nice! Sure, I was looking for that. This solves the problem. Thanks a lot for your great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the solution to your [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) is a complex number. On the other hand, your function `gcom` only works when the input is a real number. This is what the error message is telling you. One possibility is to include a real check in your conditions (this is just one possibility). For example:

```
gcom[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[
    {{x^4 - 6 x^3 + 5, Element[x, Reals] && x <= 1}},
    8 x^2 - x^7 I (* otherwise *)
]
```

*(another possibility as suggested by @Henrik in the comments is `Re[x] <= 1`)*

Then:

```
FindRoot[gcom[x], {x,10}]
```

> {x -> 1.44153 - 0.468382 I}

Comment: @Woll: This works :). Thanks a lot.